# How to delete all the subdirectories but keep those files in the parent directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, aix

I am using ksh on AIX, and my directory structure is like below.

```
dir/
    subdir1/file1
    subdir2/file2
    subdir3/file3
```

I want to delete all the subdirectories `subdir1`, `subdir2`, and so on.  I want to  keep the files, `file1`, `file2` and so on, in `dir`. Said another way, I want to move all the files in the `subdirs` to the `dir` and then delete all the empty `subdirs`. So the final result would be:

```
dir/
    file1
    file2
    file3
    ....
```

What command should I use?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use the `find` command which should work in any shell:

```
find ./dir -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} ./dir/ \;
```

This starts from `./dir` and finds files below the first-level of `./dir` and then moves those files to `./dir`.

To remove empty subdirectories, use:

```
find ./dir -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

**Warning**: This will overwrite files with the same name should there be file name collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Move up the files first, and then remove the empty subdirectories; from the `dir/`:

```
mv subdir*/file* ./ && rmdir subdir*/
```

The `/` after directory name indicates that we are dealing with a directory. You can get more precise with globbing by using `?` or `[:digit:]` to match the file/directory names though.

Comment: May be `rmdir` would be better than `rm -r`, as OP intends to remove empty directories only.  So, `mv subdir*/file* ./ && rmdir subdir*/`.

Comment: @codeforester Yeah, did not read carefully...that makes sense, edited. Thanks.